# Execute Selenium Python Code in a For Loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a script call create_cpe.py
It open up firefox and create a cpe.

---

## create_cpe.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re
import random
import requests

class CreateCPE(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://localhost:8888"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_create_c_p_e(self):

        mac = [ 0x00, 0x24, 0x81,
        random.randint(0x00, 0x7f),
        random.randint(0x00, 0xff),
        random.randint(0x00, 0xff) ]
        cpe_mac =  ':'.join(map(lambda x: "%02x" % x, mac))
        cpe_mac = cpe_mac.replace(":","").upper()
        rand_cpe_name = "Bunlong's AP " + str(random.randint(2,99))

        url = "https://randomuser.me/api/"
        data = requests.get(url).json()

        add1 = data['results'][0]['location']['street']
        city = data['results'][0]['location']['city']
        state = data['results'][0]['location']['state']
        postcode = data['results'][0]['location']['postcode']


        print rand_cpe_name
        print cpe_mac

        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("admin@benunets.com")
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("admin")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/account/1001/cpe/create")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".add-location").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("add1").send_keys(add1)
        driver.find_element_by_name("add2").send_keys("")
        driver.find_element_by_name("city").send_keys(city)
        driver.find_element_by_name("state").send_keys(state)
        driver.find_element_by_name("zip").send_keys(postcode)
        driver.find_element_by_name("country").send_keys("USA")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("mac").send_keys(cpe_mac)
        driver.find_element_by_name("cpe_name").send_keys(rand_cpe_name)
        driver.find_element_by_name("p_ip").send_keys("192.168.9.2")
        driver.find_element_by_name("p_netmask").send_keys("255.255.255.0")
        driver.find_element_by_name("p_max_user").send_keys("50")
        driver.find_element_by_name("dns").send_keys("172.16.0.73")
        driver.find_element_by_name("dns2").send_keys("172.16.0.74")
        Select(driver.find_element_by_name("g_max_up")).select_by_visible_text("256 Kbps")
        Select(driver.find_element_by_name("g_max_down")).select_by_visible_text("2000 Kbps")
        driver.find_element_by_name("g_dns2").send_keys("172.16.0.74")
        driver.find_element_by_name("g_portal").send_keys("http://www.bunlongheng.com")
        driver.find_element_by_name("g_netmask").send_keys("255.255.255.0")
        driver.find_element_by_name("g_max_user").send_keys("40")
        driver.find_element_by_name("g_dns").send_keys("172.16.0.74")
        driver.find_element_by_name("dns2").send_keys("172.16.0.75")
        driver.find_element_by_name("g_dns2").send_keys("172.16.0.76")
        driver.find_element_by_name("g_ip").send_keys("192.168.9.3")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-success").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

It works when I run `python create_cpe.py`

---

## Now

I'm take it to the next level.
I'm trying to create a for loop and run that same script

```
import os
cpe = raw_input("How many CPE you want to create ? : ")
for x in xrange(int(cpe)):
    os.system("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python/create_cpe.py")

print cpe + ' new CPE(s) inserted !'
```

and I got

```
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.common.by
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.common.keys
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.support.ui
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.common.exceptions
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.common.exceptions
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python/create_cpe.py: line 8: import: command not found
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python/create_cpe.py: line 9: import: command not found
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python/create_cpe.py: line 10: import: command not found
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python/create_cpe.py: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python/create_cpe.py: line 12: `class CreateCPE(unittest.TestCase):'
```

---

Did I missed anything ?

Should I try something elses ?

Why it is not working when I use the for loop to execute it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

os.system is running it like it's a bash script. The line that runs it should be

```
os.system("python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python/create_cpe.py")
```